# Would have in hypothetical situation when talking about past

Tags: tense

If I am talking about the yesterday's match and I am assuming a hypothetical situation, what should I say:

> 1.If I was/were/had been the captain of England cricket I **would have chosen** to bat after winning the toss.(It is very less likely that I could the captain).

Or

> 2.If I was/were/had been the captain of England cricket I **would choose** to bat after winning the toss.(It is very less likely that I could the captain).

Which one is correct?

Comment: what do you mean by "It is very less likely that I could the captain"?

Comment: Since you are talking about a specific match, it is better to say *if I had been the England captain, I would have chosen...*. The version with *were* is either general (any time I was in that situation I would...) or relates to a future situation - you could use it for example if you were talking about a specific match, but speaking before the decision has been made.